# frbs rule base or in R

Tags: r, fuzzy-logic

I've been trying to use the R Statistical software to build a fuzzy inference system(FIS). Using the R package 'frbs' I've managed to set up the most of components of the FIS following the example in the demo files.  Unfortunately I've hit a problem:

I want to modify the Rule base from using 'and' to 'or'.  The modification is no problem but the frbs.gen command only seems to able to generate rules using 'and'. Although I saw in the help file rule base were some examples that used the 'or' logical operator. Here's the URL for the help file: `http://127.0.0.1:12572/library/frbs/html/rulebase.html`

when I rerun the `frbs.gen` command it seems to automatically still use the original rule base. It ignored the changes that I made to the `rule` variable and continues to use the 'and' logical operator even when I changed the rule base. T_T anybody else having the same issues?

PS. Updated to the latest version of R(3.1.2) and even tried it on an older version R(3.0.2) but frbs.gen still won't use/allow the 'or' logical operator....

Here's the full code.

```
> demo(FRBS.Mamdani.Manual)


    demo(FRBS.Mamdani.Manual)
    ---- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Type  <Return>   to start : 

>  ## This example shows how to use frbs without 
>  ## learning process.
>  ## Note: some variables might be shared for other examples.
> 
>  ## Define shape and parameters of membership functions of input variables.
>  ## Please see fuzzifier function to contruct the matrix.

varinp.mf <- matrix(c(2, 0, 20, 40, NA, 4, 20, 40, 60, 80, 3, 60, 80, 100, NA,
+                        2, 0, 35, 75, NA, 3, 35, 75, 100, NA,
+                        2, 0, 20, 40, NA, 1, 20, 50, 80, NA, 3, 60, 80, 100, NA,
+                        2, 0, 20, 40, NA, 4, 20, 40, 60, 80, 3, 60, 80, 100, NA),
+                        nrow = 5, byrow = FALSE)

>  ## Define number of fuzzy terms of input variables.
>  ## Suppose, we have 3, 2, 3, and 3 numbers of fuzzy terms 
>  ## for first, second, third and fourth variables, respectively.
>  num.fvalinput <- matrix(c(3, 2, 3, 3), nrow=1)

>  ## Give the names of the fuzzy terms of each input variable.
>  ## It should be noted that the names of the fuzzy terms must be unique,
>  ## so we put a number for making it unique.
>  varinput.1 <- c("a1", "a2", "a3")

>  varinput.2 <- c("b1", "b2")

>  varinput.3 <- c("c1", "c2", "c3")

>  varinput.4 <- c("d1", "d2", "d3")

>  names.varinput <- c(varinput.1, varinput.2, varinput.3, varinput.4)

>  ## Set interval of data.
>  range.data <- matrix(c(0,100, 0, 100, 0, 100, 0, 100, 0, 100), nrow=2)

>  ## Set weighted average method to be used as defuzzification method.
>  type.defuz <- "WAM"

>  ## We are using standard t-norm and s-norm.
>  type.tnorm <- "MIN"

>  type.snorm <- "MAX"

>  type.implication.func <- "ZADEH"

>  ## Give the name of simulation.
>  name <- "Sim-0"

>  ## Provide new data for testing. 
>  newdata<- matrix(c(25, 40, 35, 15, 45, 75, 78, 70), nrow= 2, byrow = TRUE)

>  ## the names of variables
>  colnames.var <- c("input1", "input2", "input3", "input4", "output1")

>  ###################################################################
>  ## 1. The following codes show how to generate a fuzzy model using the frbs.gen function
>  ## 1a. Using Mamdani Model 
>  ####################################################################
>  ## Define number of fuzzy terms of output variable.
>  ## In this case, we set the number of fuzzy terms to 3.
>  num.fvaloutput <- matrix(c(3), nrow=1)

>  ## Give the names of the fuzzy terms of the output variable.
>  ## Note: the names of the fuzzy terms must be unique.
>  varoutput.1 <- c("e1", "e2", "e3")

>  names.varoutput <- c(varoutput.1)

>  ## Define the shapes and parameters of the membership functions of the output variables.
>  varout.mf <- matrix(c(2, 0, 20, 40, NA, 4, 20, 40, 60, 80, 3, 60, 80, 100, NA),
+                        nrow = 5, byrow = FALSE)

>  ## Set type of model which is 1 or 2 for Mamdani or Takagi Sugeno Kang model, respectively.
>  ## In this case, we choose Mamdani model.
>  type.model <- "MAMDANI"

>  ## Define the fuzzy IF-THEN rules; 
>  ## there are two kinds of model: Mamdani and Takagi Sugeno Kang model
>  ## if we use the Mamdani model then the consequent part is a linguistic term,
>  ## but if we use Takagi Sugeno Kang then we build a matrix representing 
>  ## linear equations in the consequent part.
>  ## In this example we are using the Mamdani model 
>  ## (see the type.model parameter). 
>  ## Note:
>  ## "a1", "and", "b1, "->", "e1" means that "IF inputvar.1 is a1 and inputvar.2 is b1 THEN           outputvar.1 is e1" 
>  ## Make sure that each rule has a "->" sign. 
>  rule <- matrix(c("a1","and","b1","and","c1","and","d1","->","e1",
+                   "a2","and","b2","and","c2","and","d2", "->", "e2", 
+                   "a3","and","b2","and","c2","and","d1", "->", "e3"), 
+                   nrow=3, byrow=TRUE) 

>  ## Generate a fuzzy model with frbs.gen.
>  object <- frbs.gen(range.data, num.fvalinput, names.varinput, num.fvaloutput, varout.mf, 
+                                       names.varoutput, rule, varinp.mf, type.model, type.defuz,     type.tnorm, 
+                   type.snorm, func.tsk = NULL, colnames.var, type.implication.func, name)

>  ## We can plot the membership function
>  plotMF(object)
Waiting to confirm page change...

>  ## Predicting using new data.
>  res <- predict(object, newdata)$predicted.val
```

End of R-demo file. The next part is where I adjust the rule base then rebuild the FIS before finally checking which rule base it used.

```
> rule
     [,1] [,2]  [,3] [,4]  [,5] [,6]  [,7] [,8] [,9]
[1,] "a1" "and" "b1" "and" "c1" "and" "d1" "->" "e1"
[2,] "a2" "and" "b2" "and" "c2" "and" "d2" "->" "e2"
[3,] "a3" "and" "b2" "and" "c2" "and" "d1" "->" "e3"
> rule <- matrix(c("a1","or","b1","or","c1","or","d1","->","e1",         "a2","and","b2","and","c2","and","d2", "->", "e2", 
+ "a3","and","b2","and","c2","and","d1", "->", "e3"),
+ nrow=3, byrow=TRUE)
> rule
     [,1] [,2]  [,3] [,4]  [,5] [,6]  [,7] [,8] [,9]
[1,] "a1" "or"  "b1" "or"  "c1" "or"  "d1" "->" "e1"
[2,] "a2" "and" "b2" "and" "c2" "and" "d2" "->" "e2"
[3,] "a3" "and" "b2" "and" "c2" "and" "d1" "->" "e3"
> object <- frbs.gen(range.data, num.fvalinput, names.varinput, num.fvaloutput, varout.mf, 
+ names.varoutput, rule, varinp.mf, type.model, type.defuz, type.tnorm, 
+ 
+ type.snorm, func.tsk = NULL, colnames.var, type.implication.func, name)
> object
$num.labels
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    3    2    3    3    3

$varout.mf
     e1 e2  e3
[1,]  2  4   3
[2,]  0 20  60
[3,] 20 40  80
[4,] 40 60 100
[5,] NA 80  NA



 $rule
     [,1] [,2]  [,3] [,4] [,5]  [,6][,7] [,8] [,9]  [,10]    [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14][,15]     [,16] [,17]  [,18][,19] [,20]
[1,] "IF" "input1" "is" "a1" "and" "input2" "is" "b1" "and" "input3" "is"  "c1"  "and" "input4"              
"is"  "d1"  "THEN" "output1" "is"  "e1" 
[2,] "IF" "input1" "is" "a2" "and" "input2" "is" "b2" "and" "input3" "is"  "c2"  "and" "input4"     
"is"  "d2"  "THEN" "output1" "is"  "e2" 
[3,] "IF" "input1" "is" "a3" "and" "input2" "is" "b2" "and" "input3" "is"  "c2"  "and" "input4" 
"is"  "d1"  "THEN" "output1" "is"  "e3" 

$varinp.mf
     a1 a2  a3 b1  b2 c1 c2  c3 d1 d2  d3
[1,]  2  4   3  2   3  2  1   3  2  4   3
[2,]  0 20  60  0  35  0 20  60  0 20  60
[3,] 20 40  80 35  75 20 50  80 20 40  80
[4,] 40 60 100 75 100 40 80 100 40 60 100
[5,] NA 80  NA NA  NA NA NA  NA NA 80  NA

$range.data.ori
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    0    0    0    0
[2,]  100  100  100  100  100

$type.model
[1] "MAMDANI"

$type.tnorm
[1] "MIN"

$type.implication.func
[1] "ZADEH"

$type.mf
[1] "MIX"

$type.defuz
[1] "WAM"

$type.snorm
[1] "MAX"

$func.tsk
NULL

$method.type
[1] "MANUAL"

$name
[1] "Sim-0"

$colnames.var
[1] "input1"  "input2"  "input3"  "input4"  "output1"

$class
function (x)  .Primitive("class")

attr(,"class")
[1] "frbs"
```

Comment: If you provide a reproducible example it will be easier for us who are not familiar with this package to help you. Your other option is to contact the package author or maintainer. Third option is to wait for someone with intimate knowledge of the package to pop by.

Comment: Thank for the reply. I didn't use any personal data at all, the code and data used in my post was all from the demo within the frbs package. It's straight forward to replicate. Just run the demo and adjust the input variable 'rule', then rerun the frbs.gen function.  :<  

I wont' change the rule base logical operator 'and' to 'or'.... T_T

Comment: I recommend you make the question self-contained (for future generation(s)), which means including the full example that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: Understood, thx for the advice. I'll edit the post to cover the full example.

Answer (score 1):

I've sent an email to the authors.  They mentioned that it is a bug in the code, so they'll fix it and upload the latest version to CRAN asap.  Here's the email response from the author:

> Hi Harakhun,
>
> First of all, I want to thank you for pointing me out the bug on our package. Indeed, there was a wrong code on converting the rulebase, and I just fixed it. So, herewith I enclosed the package installer with version 3.0-0 in .zip for windows and .tar.gz for unix. You can use the refined package by installing it from the local file. Moreover, I attach an example using the "and" and "or" operators in the R script. Please let me know if you have any further problems.
>
> The updated package along with new features will be submitted to CRAN as soon as possible.
>
> Best regards,
>
> Lala SR.

Comment: Could you please direct me to where can I find the example explaining how to user "or" and "and" operators.